# What is the Linux equivalent of: MultiByteToWideChar & WideCharToMultiByte?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, unicode, stdstring

I am working with a class that wraps the std::wstring, this code needs to be cross platform, are there equivalents to the windows functions: MultiByteToWideChar & WideCharToMultiByte on linux?

Thank you.

Comment: Remember that on GNU/Linux, std::wstring is twice the size of std::wstring on Windows.

Comment: There are the C99 functios mbtowc and wctomb for this

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: `mbtowc` and `wctomb` were actually added in Normative Amendment 1 in 1995.

Answer (score 19):

The Linux equivalents are the `iconv` functions [`iconv_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv_open), [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv) and [`iconv_close`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv_close) (say `man 3 iconv_open` etc. for the documentation). For cross-platform applications, use dedicated libraries such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) instead. Such libraries already contain their own string classes; there is no need to wrap `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 6):

`mbtowc` and `wctomb` are the most direct equivalents, but note that they operate on the multibyte character set corresponding to the current `LC_CTYPE` locale (which can be changed with `setlocale()`).