# Convert a char array of escaped UTF-8 octets to a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, utf-8, char

I have a char array containing some UTF-8-encoded Turkish characters - in the form of escaped octets. Thus if I run this code in C++11:

```
void foo(char* utf8_encoded) { 

    cout << utf8_encoded << endl;

}
```

it prints `\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e`. I want to convert this `char[]` to an `std::string` so that it contains UTF-8 decoded values `İ-Ç-Ü-Ğ`. I have converted that `char[]` to `wstring` but it still prints as `\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e`. How can I do that?

**EDIT:** I'm not the one who constructs this char[]. It is one of the static-length parameter of a callback function called by a private library. So the callback function is as follows:

```
void some_callback_function (INFO *info) { 

    cout << info->some_char_array << endl;
    cout << "*****" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<64; i++) {
        cout << "-" << info->some_char_array[i];
    }
    cout << "*****" << endl;

    char bar[65] = "\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e";
    cout << bar << endl;
}
```

Where the `INFO` struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    char some_char_array[65];
} INFO;
```

So when my callback function is called, the output is as follows:

```
\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e
*****
-\-x-c-4-\-x-b-0---\-x-c-3-\-x-8-7---\-x-c-3-\-x-9-c---\-x-c-4-\-x-9-e-----------------------------
*****
İ-Ç-Ü-Ğ
```

So my current question is, I didn't get the difference between `info->some_char_array` and `bar` char arrays. What I want is to edit `info->some_char_array` such that, it prints the output as `İ-Ç-Ü-Ğ`.

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, src, srclen, dst, dstlen); ?

Comment: I'm working on Linux.

Comment: Can you show how you've initialized your parameter ?

Comment: @Christophe Actually this char[] is provided to me by a private API callback, so I don't have an access to the way it is initialised. I can only print it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/kOKJBK Either your string is not what you think (print hex value byte by byte to be sure), or your console locale is not utf-8

Comment: When I copied your code into my environment, Turkish characters are successfully printed. So there is a problem with my char[] I guess. How can I print hex value byte by byte?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Linux equivalent of: MultiByteToWideChar & WideCharToMultiByte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277013/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-multibytetowidechar-widechartomultibyte)

Comment: How did you convert to `wstring` and how did you print the `wstring`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can know what's going wrong.

Comment: I am *very* confused about this question. `\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e` **is** the UTF-8 sequence for the characters `İ-Ç-Ü-Ğ`...?!? What "conversion" are you looking for? What do you mean with "UTF-8 decoded"? (And at everybody, what's with the `wstring`? That's not the question, UTF-8 is...) Do you get `\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e`, verbatim, i.e. the character sequence `'\'`, `'x'`, `'c'` and so on? Then your *calling* code (which you didn't show) did something **very** strange. Seconding xskxzr, we need a [mcve], with input, observed output, and expected output.

Comment: Or are you looking for the conversion of `{ '\', 'x', 'c', '4', ... }` to a proper UTF-8 string?

Comment: OK, it's much clearer now. Clearer, but not exactly easy. Question: Would it be OK for you if I posted an answer that would involve to (common) external libraries? Namely [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) and [Boost](http://boost.org)? Because I have the relevant source "lying around"...

Comment: I am implementing in arm architecture, and my libraries are restricted, but Boost would be OK. Frankly, I believe that this problem might be solved by editing the current char array by putting a special character such as "\0". I have already converted it to a string, which is null-terminated, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @lsalamon Correct me if I'm wrong, but this problem has nothing to do with base64.

Comment: @Eelke: What he has is literally a string *with escape sequences* in it. He needs to parse those escapes...

Comment: I think your terminology is off. By "UTF-8 decoded" you mean "UTF-8 encoded", and by "UTF-8 encoded" you mean "encoded in ASCII as a sequence of C-like character escapes denoting the values of constituent Unicode codepoints". Amirite?

Comment: Hang on, I must be wrong, as `some_callback_function` cannot possibly give the result you claim. Dafraq?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually I thought that both char arrays I have are UTF-8 supported, but the first one doesn't show the symbols, but in hexadecimal codes. That's why it seemed like a "decoded" version to me.

Comment: @cagrias: Maybe you should tell/show us _exactly_ what you see. C++ doesn't "support" UTF-8 in any way at all - you just have a bunch of bytes, and a terminal that may or may not be interpreting them in a certain way. But it's really unclear at the moment what your situation is.

Comment: @cagrias: UTF-8 would be the hexadecimal values `0xc4 0xb0 0x27 0xc3 0x87` and so on (the `0x27` being the `'-'`). What you (seem to) get as input here is an ASCII "escape sequence", where e.g. the hex value `0xc4` is represented by the [character literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) sequence `{ '\\', 'x', 'c', '4' }`. That's highly unusual, unless you're parsing C/C++ source...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think my terminal is fine, as my own defined char array "bar" is printed out exactly the way I want. As you said, I want the easiest way to convert these character literal sequence to a readable string.

Comment: @cagrias: But your function `some_callback_function` doesn't produce character literal sequences! I know you can see them in its source code, but that's because it's source code... It's just... not possible for the result to be as you've claimed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So thats why the only way is to use some other external libraries I guess?

Comment: No... it's why you need to clarify what's really going on.

Comment: The things I provided on EDIT part is all I know about what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is a bit of a handful, ripped out of a larger parser I am using. But "a bit of a handful" is the nature of [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/). ;-)

The parser will not only parse hexadecimal escapes, but octals (`\123`) and "standard" escapes (`\n`) as well. Provided under CC0, so you can do with it whatever you like. ;-)

Boost.Spirit is a "header only" part of Boost, so you don't need to link in any library code. The rather involved "magic" done by the Spirit headers to allow grammars expressed in C++ source this way is a bit hard on the compile time, though.

But it works, and works well.

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace
{

// Helper function: Turn on_error positional parameters into error message.
template< typename Iterator >
std::string make_error_message( boost::spirit::info const & info, Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Invalid sequence. Expecting " << info << " here: \"" << std::string( first, last ) << "\"";
    return oss.str();
}

}

// Wrap helper function with Boost.Phoenix boilerplate, so the function
// can be called from within a parser's [].
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION( std::string, make_error_message_, make_error_message, 3 )

// Supports various escape sequences:
// - Character escapes ( \a \b \f \n \r \t \v \" \\ )
// - Octal escapes ( \n \nn \nnn )
// - Hexadecimal escapes ( \xnn ) (*)
//
// (*): In C/C++, a hexadecimal escape runs until the first non-hexdigit
//      is encountered, which is not very helpful. This one takes exactly
//      two hexdigits.

// Declaring a grammer that works given any kind of iterator,
// and results in a std::string object.
template < typename Iterator >
class EscapedString : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar< Iterator, std::string() >
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        EscapedString() : EscapedString::base_type( escaped_string )
        {
            // An escaped string is a sequence of
            // characters that are not '\', or
            // an escape sequence
            escaped_string = *( +( boost::spirit::ascii::char_ - '\\' ) | escapes );

            // An escape sequence begins with '\', followed by
            // an escaped character (e.g. "\n"), or
            // an 'x' and 2..2 hexadecimal digits, or
            // 1..3 octal digits.
            escapes = '\\' > ( escaped_character
                               | ( "x" > boost::spirit::qi::uint_parser< char, 16, 2, 2 >() )
                               | boost::spirit::qi::uint_parser< char, 8, 1, 3 >() );

            // The list of special "escape" characters
            escaped_character.add
            ( "a", 0x07 )  // alert
            ( "b", 0x08 )  // backspace
            ( "f", 0x0c )  // form feed
            ( "n", 0x0a )  // new line
            ( "r", 0x0d )  // carriage return
            ( "t", 0x09 )  // horizontal tab
            ( "v", 0x0b )  // vertical tab
            ( "\"", 0x22 ) // literal quotation mark
            ( "\\", 0x5c ) // literal backslash
            ;

            // Error handling
            boost::spirit::qi::on_error< boost::spirit::qi::fail >
            (
                escapes,
                // backslash not followed by a valid sequence
                boost::phoenix::throw_(
                    boost::phoenix::construct< std::runtime_error >( make_error_message_( boost::spirit::_4, boost::spirit::_3, boost::spirit::_2 ) )
                )
            );
        }

    private:
        // Qi Rule member
        boost::spirit::qi::rule< Iterator, std::string() > escaped_string;

        // Helpers
        boost::spirit::qi::rule< Iterator, std::string() > escapes;
        boost::spirit::qi::symbols< char const, char > escaped_character;
};


int main()
{
    // Need to escape the backslashes, or "\xc4" would give *one*
    // byte of output (0xc4, decimal 196). I understood the input
    // to be the FOUR character hex char literal,
    // backslash, x, c, 4 in this case,
    // which is what this string literal does.
    char * some_char_array = "\\xc4\\xb0-\\xc3\\x87-\\xc3\\x9c-\\xc4\\x9e";

    std::cout << "Input: '" << some_char_array << "'\n";

    // result object    
    std::string s;

    // Create an instance of the grammar with "char *"
    // as the iterator type.
    EscapedString< char * > es;

    // start, end, parsing grammar, result object
    boost::spirit::qi::parse( some_char_array,
                              some_char_array + std::strlen( some_char_array ),
                              es,
                              s );

    std::cout << "Output: '" << s << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
Input: '\xc4\xb0-\xc3\x87-\xc3\x9c-\xc4\x9e'
Output: 'İ-Ç-Ü-Ğ'
```

Comment: The original code uses ICU to also do Unicode escapes (`\uxxxx` and `\Uxxxxxxxx`), but I edited those out as you didn't state whether those would be necessary, or ICU "allowed" in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got "'UChar32' was not declared in this scope" error when compiling. But adding "#include <unicode/unistr.h>" still gives the same error.

Comment: Bugger, forgot to take that out as well.. Give me a minute.

Comment: @cagrias: There, that should have been `char` after I took out the ICU stuff. (The original code uses UTF-32 internally and converts the string to UTF-16 in the end. Some artifacts remained in there after I gutted it and made it play UTF-8. Sorry for that.)

Comment: @cagrias: Does this work for you? Should I take the non-hex parts out of my answer to make it more "streamlined" / acceptable? Did I miss something?

Comment: I have tried your code, which worked successfully. Thanks.

Comment: Nice job. I need to play with Spirit myself one of these days.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's one hell of a beast to wrestle with. If you don't get it right, the error messages from this heavily templated code can drive you absolutely nuts. The compile times are also a handful. But if you *do* get it right... "I am a leaf on the wind; watch how I soar." Being able to express parser grammer directly in C++, and have the parser spit out the abstract syntax tree in form of C++ objects, is just so much beyond what Flex / Bison can do for you... I hope that C++ Contracts will make the error messages more palatable.

Comment: @DevSolar: I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that the quoted line was directly followed by being fatally impaled through the heart.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: :-)